# Probability brain teaser 20 sided die

Tags: probability

A fair 20 sided die (1-20) is rolled 20 times. The rolls are summed. If roll 1 all 20 times, the sum is 20.

Exactly 99% of the time, the sum will be less than what number?

I run a simulation, and get the result to be 270. Not sure how to calculate it.

Comment: If you don't mind the use of technology, consider the generating function $(\frac{1}{20}(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{20}))^{20}$.  Add the coefficients from $x^{20}$ (*the lowest possible*) up until you first get a value of $0.99$ (*or greater*).

Comment: what if its not whole

Comment: "what if its not whole" then the problem is not written correctly and there is no number such that **exactly** 99% of the time the sum will be less than it.  In any case, summing the coefficients of $x^k$ in the given generating function will tell you the exact probability of getting a sum of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

The generating function $(\frac{1}{20}(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{20}))^{20}=\frac{1}{20^{20}}x^{20}+\frac{20}{20^{20}}x^{21}+\frac{210}{20^{20}}x^{22}+\frac{1540}{20^{20}}x^{23}+\dots+\frac{1}{20^{20}}x^{400}$ has the property that the coefficient of $x^k$ corresponds to the probability that you get a sum of exactly $k$ when throwing twenty fair twenty-sided dice.

With the use of a computer, you could calculate the coefficients of all 381 terms that appear in the expansion and add terms until reaching the desired amount.  Be warned though, $20^{20}\approx 1.05\cdot 10^{26}$ so you will likely need to rely on biginteger or similar classes depending on your programming language.